# Heteroskedastic consistent covariance matrix with univariate regression [R]

Tags: r

How can I calculate the heteroskedastic consistent covariance matrix (HCCM) for a univariate regression (i.e., an OLS regression with one regressor and no intercept)?

Back story: I have a fixed effect panel regression, but with only one regressor. So I can do it with either the least squares dummy variable (LSDV) approach

```
lm.ser.yr <- lm(realwage ~ placebo.ser + factor(incyear) + 0, data = cps)
```

or I can demean the LHS at the year level and regress

```
cps <- ddply(cps, .(incyear), transform, realwage.dm.yr = realwage - mean(realwage))
lm.ser.yr <- lm(realwage.dm.yr ~ placebo.ser + 0, data = cps)
```

But there are problems with both.

- With the LSDV approach and enough dummies the `lm` object gets huge (1 gb each). This is mostly because of the large `qr` matrix that I have to keep to pass it to `vcovHC()` to calculate the HCCM, which is frequently stops on "can't allocate vector of size" errors (or does a lot of paging).
- With the demeaned within estimator everything works great, but I can't calculate the HCCM because neither `vcovHC()` or `hccm()` have handle the no intercept univariate `lm` object (i.e., it spits back `NA`, which as best I can tell is because without the intercept and dummy variables, my residuals are much farther from zero mean).

Is there a solution to this short of very aggressively managing memory and/or moving to the cloud?

Comment: Might belong on math.overflow.com

Comment: @duffymo -- It might. I think this is an econometrics/computation issue, and I feel like a see more of those here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vcovHC()` from the `plm` package seems to handle `lm()` models without intercepts perfectly fine:

```
library(plm)
df <- data.frame('a'=rnorm(1000), 'b'=rnorm(1000))
mod <- lm(a ~ b -1, df)
vcovHC(mod)
```

Edit: here's some code to calculate them manually.

```
library(Matrix)
e2 = mod$residuals ^ 2
X = model.matrix(mod)
N = nrow(X)
bread = solve(crossprod(X))
I <- Matrix(data=0, ncol=N, nrow=N, sparse=TRUE)
diag(I) <- e2
salami <- t(X) %*% I %*% X 
V = bread %*% salami %*% bread
```

Comment: @Vincent -- Thanks much! I had tinkered with `plm`, but got a little overwhelmed by all the settings... I had completely forgot that they have their own `vcovHC()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent -- I jinxed myself. I didn't look at all of the results and missed two that fail -- so it's not really a "univariate" problem, it must be that I have a model with too large of residuals that won't solve properly (I guess here `mod` would have to be `plm` to invoke `vcovHC.plm`). I'll dig further into `sandwich` and see what I can find.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the White errors by hand? That way you'll see where it fails. It's really easy to implement, so you might as well try that.

Comment: When I run your code I get this error: `Error in array(0, c(n, p)) : 'dim' specifies too large an array`

Comment: I'll stick with the dummy variables for now (this may be complicated by the one regressor being an indicator variable). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vincent -- and the same error persists if I convert explicitly to scalars: `X <- as.matrix(cps$placebo.ser, ncol = 1); as.numeric(X2) * as.numeric(t(X) %*% diag(e2) %*% X) * as.numeric(X2)` yields error `Error in array(0, c(n, p)) : 'dim' specifies too large an array`

Comment: I should not try to write code this late. Here's a working version. If you're truly just doing a bivariate regression, you'll need a HUGE number of observations to run against the memory limit. In any case, I also make use of sparse matrices to minimize memory usage on that identity matrix operation. So that could help a bit too.

Comment: @Vincent -- Thank you very much! That did the trick! (I edited so that it returns a `matrix` instead of a `dgeMatrix` for downstream compatibility)